# Unable to change background color dynamically using react hooks and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change the color of 3 HTML div's dynamically but the code below does not seem to be working.

```
function App() {
  const [redBgColor, setRedBgColor] = useState(null)
  const [yellowBgColor, setYellowBgColor] = useState(null)
  const [greenBgColor, setGreenBgColor] = useState(null)
  // const [bgImage, setBgImage] = useState("")

  setTimeout(function() {
    stop();
  }, 100);

  function stop() {
    setRedBgColor('#FF0000');
    setYellowBgColor('');
    setGreenBgColor('');

    setTimeout(wait, 4000);
  }

  function wait() {
    setRedBgColor('');
    setYellowBgColor('#FBFF00');
    setGreenBgColor('');
    setTimeout(go, 2000);
  }

  function go() {
    setRedBgColor('');
    setYellowBgColor('');
    setGreenBgColor('#00FF00');  
    setTimeout(stop, 5000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        
        <div className="flexbox-container" >
          <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1" style={{ backgroundColor: `${redBgColor}` }}></div>
          <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2" style={{ backgroundColor: `${yellowBgColor}` }}></div>
          <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3" style={{ backgroundColor: `${greenBgColor}` }}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

Can someone help me out ?

I tried using setTimeout to change the colors dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within your `App` function/component runs every time your component rerenders. That means that when it first mounts, your `App` function executes leading to you calling `setTimeout`. This timeout eventually calls `stop()`, which calls your state setter functions. When you call a state setter function, your component rerenders with the new state values you had previously set. However, as you're calling `setTimeout()` at the top-level of your component function, this ends up calling `setTimeout()` again when `App` executes to perform the rerender. As a result, another timeout gets queued and this cycle contains, causing you to have multiple timeouts all running at the same time which are trying to update your state.

Instead, you should only begin your timeout once when your component loads, which you can do by using the [`useEffect()` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect). In addition, you should clear your timeouts if your component unmounts (this is good to do as it could result in you trying to update state for a component that no longer exists):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React; 
function App() {
  const [redBgColor, setRedBgColor] = useState(null)
  const [yellowBgColor, setYellowBgColor] = useState(null);
  const [greenBgColor, setGreenBgColor] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let activeTimeout;
    activeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      stop();
    }, 100);

    function stop() {
      setRedBgColor('#FF0000');
      setYellowBgColor('');
      setGreenBgColor('');

      activeTimeout = setTimeout(wait, 4000);
    }

    function wait() {
      setRedBgColor('');
      setYellowBgColor('#FBFF00');
      setGreenBgColor('');
      activeTimeout = setTimeout(go, 2000);
    }

    function go() {
      setRedBgColor('');
      setYellowBgColor('');
      setGreenBgColor('#00FF00');  
      activeTimeout = setTimeout(stop, 5000);
    }
    
    return () => { // when the component unmounts, this function will execute, cleaning up any timers running.
      clearTimeout(activeTimeout);
    }

  }, []); // empty array here means only execute the above useEffect callback function on mount (ie: load) of the component

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="flexbox-container" >
        <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1" style={{ backgroundColor: `${redBgColor}` }}></div>
        <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2" style={{ backgroundColor: `${yellowBgColor}` }}></div>
        <div className="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3" style={{ backgroundColor: `${greenBgColor}` }}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain how the useEffect() hook is actually working ?

Comment: Check out the link in my answer, that explains it quite well. The general idea is that it executes some code after a render if the values passed to the array (2nd argument) has changed from the previous render. When the array is empty, it executes the function only after the initial render/mount

Comment: Inside stop(), there are 3 statements to change states. I want to know whether the UI will be rendered 3  times or only once during execution of stop().

Comment: All of the setXYZ() calls within stop will be batched together and only cause 1 rerender. However, your component will rerender again once when wait() is called and again when go() is called